# Simple.Odata.Client Retrieve Data From WCF Dataservice

Tags: wcf, odata, dataservice

My wcf dataservice is using self-host,When I tried to retrieve data from wcf dataservice by simploe.odata.client,it throws a error:Internal Server Error.
wcf dataservice code:`public class RFODataService : DataService<RFODBEntities>
    {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule(typeof(DETAIL).Name, EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule(typeof(HEADER).Name, EntitySetRights.All);
        }
    }`

self-host code:`var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType());
            if (currentAssembly == null)
                return "Assembly not found";
            var types = currentAssembly.GetTypes().Where(w => w.IsClass && w.Namespace.Contains("DataServices")).ToArray();

```
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
        {
            var svcHost = new DataServiceHost(serviceType, new Uri[] { new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost:{0}/", Port)) });
            svcHost.Open();
        }`
```

simple.odata.client code:`var client = new ODataClient("URL");

```
        var detail = client.For("DETAIL").FindEntriesAsync();

        string temp = detail.Result.ToString();

        Console.Write(temp);`
```

It is trouble me,is there any one know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting InternalServerError it's most probably something with the service implementation or setup. I suggest you first isolate the error by running a query in the browser. Try something like SERVER_URL/Details (I assume you have an entity set called Details) and check the response from the server. If this doesn't work then your problem is the server. If it works, check your Simple.Data.Client queries by running Fiddler and inspecting HTTP traffic. If generated query is different (and wrong) you can open an issue at Simple.OData.Client GitHub site and I can investigate it.

Comment: hi,thank you for your answer,as you said,I found that Simple.OData.Client is ok, the issue is the DB connection string wrong.when i running in the browser,it's ok,but when i give a retrieve to EF from DB,it's throws exception.

Comment: hi,as the above problem,when I used simple.odata.clent into c#,it's working,but when I useed it to xamarin for android, it does't work.the step as it to c#,when it run to "string temp = detail.Result.ToString()",It is no response,do you know the reson?is it different c# and android in xamarin?thank you for your reading!

Comment: The reason is that you call detail.Result. You should await results on mobile platforms, e.g. temp = (await detail).ToString().

Comment: thank you very much!you help me to solve my trouble again.is there some document only for android platforms to develop? or some complete examples?could you give me a website?

Comment: the other question,I have a library(Target frameworks:.Net Framework 4.5,Silverlight 5,Xamarin.Android,Xamarin.IOS),when I install odata client to the library,it create folder packages,but not reference the dll,does odata client support to library?

Comment: Here's a Wiki for the library: https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/wiki.
Regarding your other question, can you please post it separately on SO with more explanation of what you're trying to achieve.